# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest setting delegate for cache policy

Tags: ios

for iOS 5.0 and arc, i need to ensure that the NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest does not cache the response data. How would I set the delegate so that I can implement the below method

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
```

Comment: Hi I face similar issue, where I need to call "[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest"] and want to trigger "willCacheResponse" delegate. Where I can't find the place to set the delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
    [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]
                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                      timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

Comment: If I view the NSURLRequest.h header it specifically notes:     `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData = 4, // Unimplemented`. With the unimplemented note, wouldn't this mean that enum option does nothing?

Comment: @Zenox Good find, you can try 'NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData' but I am not sure about the remote cache. Although the Docs does not say anything: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html